# Animation do angular só funciona na transição "enter"

Tags: html, css, angular

Estou tentando colocar um efeito de fadein/fadeout, mas só está funcionando o fadeIn, quando acontece o hide o elemento desaparece instantaneamente.

Tentei:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-confprecificacao',
  templateUrl: './confprecificacao.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confprecificacao.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [   // :enter is alias to 'void => *'
        style({opacity:0}),
        animate(500, style({opacity:1})) 
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [   // :leave is alias to '* => void'
        animate(500, style({opacity:0})) 
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

Meu template:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'transition':loadingcadastro}" [hidden]="!loadingcadastro" [@fadeInOut] id="controlaloading" class="controleloading">
    <app-loading></app-loading>
</div>
```

Troquei para:

```
<div [@hideShowAnimator]="loadingcadastro" id="controlaloading" class="controleloading">
    <app-loading></app-loading>
</div>
```

e:

```
trigger('hideShowAnimator', [
    state('true' , style({ opacity: 1 })), 
    state('false', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    transition('0 => 1', animate('.5s')),
    transition('1 => 0', animate('.5s'))
])
```

Mas agora o fadeIn não acontece.

Comment: Cara não sou especialista, mas vc tem que colocar o estado inicial e o final não? Tipo no :leave tem que estar: style({opacity:1}),
        animate(500, style({opacity:0}))  ?

Comment: Troquei colocando os estados mas agora o fadeIn que não acontece.

    trigger('hideShowAnimator', [
        state('true' , style({ opacity: 1 })), 
        state('false', style({ opacity: 0 })),
        transition('0 => 1', animate('.5s')),
        transition('1 => 0', animate('.5s'))
    ])

<div [@hideShowAnimator]="loadingcadastro" id="controlaloading" class="controleloading">
    <app-loading></app-loading>
</div>

Comment: É acho que nessa não consigo ajudar muito :/ , como disse foi só uma dica pra vc testar rss

Comment: obrigado de qualquer maneira